# Determining the distribution function of randomly sampled points in a triangle

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be the minimum of distances between randomly picked point $T$ inside an equilateral triangle $\Delta ABC$ and points of same triangle, A, B, C. Every page of that triangle has length $1$. We wish to determine the distribution function of $X$.

I drew the picture to better understand how to proceed, but I got stuck. Any hint to start would help!

Comment: The point $T$ lies inside the triangle? Or on the triangle?

Comment: @Vizag inside the triangle